# how to make a note with implementation in a UML class-diagram in visual paradigm

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

I have been looking around for this for ages, but could not find any way to link a UML note to an operation of a class or to display the provided implementation in the specification of an operation. The idea is illustrated in the picture.

[image: the goal I want to achieve]

I tried to add the implementation to the operation, but I don't manage to make it appear in my diagram. I also tried making a note and then connecting it to the method, but this leads to unclear floating line-ends.

If anybody could let me know how this could be achieved with visual paradigm or let me know it is impossible, that would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how or whether this is possible with VP (I know for sure that you can't do it with Enterprise Architect which is pretty much UML2.x compliant). But you could hook the link near the position in the appropriate compartment (EA also has a feature to lock the connector at a certain position of an element).

**Edit** I have looked into Superstructures 2.5:

> **Comment [Class]**
>
> **Description**
>
> A Comment is a textual annotation that can be attached to a set of Elements.

So actually what you want to do is not UML compliant. A comment can only be attached to an element. Attributes/operations are not UML elements.

Comment: "A UML method is the implementation of an operation; ... A method may be illustrated severaly ways, including in class diagrams, with a UML note symbol stereotyped with «method»" is a quote from applying UML and patterns from C. Larman (see updated picture in my question), so it should be UML compliant, not?

Comment: Larmann is not OMG. My citation is from the most recent UML documentation. I have seen your notation here the first time. Anyhow, I would not criticize it since it looks understandable. But tool vendors only implement what OMG publishes. So often you need some work around.

Comment: I guess I just learned more UML the last hours than I did during the whole semester. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: UML in practice often differs from what you learn in books or university. My general advice: UML is a language. And as such it can be used in (almost) any way as long as it fulfills its purpose: communication.